# Python3.. i want to update a dictionary by other dictionary's values

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

## i want to check if dict1 keys ==  dict2 keys i want to add the values from dict1 to dict2, dict2 i made dict2 values all zeros so i can add any value for dict1.

basically i am counting the duplicates for each number from 1 to 99 in dict1 then i add how many the number is duplicate in dict2 >>>

```
dict1 = {2: 6, 4: 4, 6: 4, 7: 4, 8: 3}
dict2 = {1:0, 2:0, 3:0...99:0}
```

#i want to add number 6 from dict1 to dict2 in key 2

```
from collections import Counter
arr = [2,2,2,2,2,2,4,4,4,4,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,8,8,8]
dict1 = Counter(arr)
val = dict1.keys()
val_list = list(val)
dict2 = dict.fromkeys(range(1,101),0)
values = dict2.values()
values_list = list(values)
```

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, I think the update() function can help you achieve this. `x.update(gg)` will directly change the values of all the keys of x which also occur in gg. So, the key '2' in x will get the value '6' as mentioned in gg

Answer (score 1):

The question isn't completely clear. But from what I understand you want to update all the keys that are in **x** with the corresponding values in **gg**. That can be done by

```
x.update({i:j for i,j in gg.items() if i in x.keys()})
```

Comment: tax dud its worked, and you are right i should make my question more understandable. sorry again